# Date always resets to 11 Feb 2016 on Odroid XU4, running Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: time, ubuntu-mate, date, ntp

Every time I start my odroid XU4, the date seems to be 11th Feb 2016 for some reason. `timedatectl` command shows the below result:

```
Network time on: yes 
NTP synchronized: yes 
RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: Do you have the RTC backup battery attached?, If so, check the cell battery voltage.

Comment: @GTRONICK No, I do not have a RTC backup battery. Does it have something to do with the hwclock? I tried `sudo hwclock --set --date="2017-05-16 11:57:00"` and then `sudo hwclock -s` to set the hwclock and system clock. But after shutting down and rebooting the device it goes back to Feb 11 2016.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the RTC backup battery, the system will not preserve the time. You can purchase one here: [rtc-battery](http://ameridroid.com/products/rtc-battery).

However, the time should be kept if you maintain the ODROID XU4 connected to the power supply. If this does not work, I could think this is a hardware fault. Other thing you could try, is using an external RTC module, or run an script in every reboot to sync the clock using Internet for example.

Comment: Yes, RTC battery should be one solution. But under Time and Date settings I have selected `Keep synchronized with internet servers`. If the odroid boots with the wrong date shouldn't it get updated to the correct time after few seconds?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Well, that is a strange situation, have you tried using Android, or other version of Ubuntu?

Comment: No, I have not tried with other versions.